# Back to Search Results implementation

Tags: asp.net, search, back

What's the best way to implement "Back to Search Results" in an ASP.NET application? I've been letting users do the BACK button in the browser, but they always get a prompt to resubmit the form.

Is there an effective way to work around this resubmit?

Should I cache the search criteria/url in session and redirect them when they press 'back'?

What's the best practice here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this warning when a page in the browser history was the direct result of an http POST.  This is avoided if your search form uses method GET instead of method POST.

Answer (score 2):

I'd pass the search criteria in querystring and make the back link something like `<a href='/Search.aspx?q=keywords'>Back</a>` instead.